# Why we can write $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}$ as $\frac{d\psi(x,y)}{dx}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading Boyce/Diprima/Meade's book, in this example:

> [image]

It's not clear to me why we can write $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}$ as $\frac{d\psi(x,y)}{dx}$, I think we can write $\frac{d \psi(x,y)}{d y}\frac{dy}{dx}$ as $\frac{d \psi(x,y)}{d y}$ due to the chain rule, so we get:

$$\frac{d \psi(x,y)}{dx}+ \frac{d \psi(x,y)}{d y}$$

I computed this and obtained the original differential equation, so I might be on the right path. But I still don't get the part where we write it as

$$\frac{d\psi(x,y)}{dx}$$

Can you help me?

Comment: Just indicating it’s a partial derivative as opposed to the derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a notation problem in calculus.  Unfortunately, partial differentials suffer from a terrible notation problem.  The actual truth about partial differentials is very straightforward: since $\psi$ is a function of independent variables $y$ and $x$, the total change of $\psi$ is the combination of the change in $\psi$ due to $x$ and the change in $\psi$ due to $y$.  This can be written straightforwardly as:

$$ d\psi = \partial_x \psi + \partial_y \psi$$

Here, the subscripts show which variable is allowed to change.

We can get from this to the equation as follows:

(1) Divide both sides by $dx$:

$$ \frac{d\psi}{dx} = \frac{\partial_x \psi}{dx} + \frac{\partial_y \psi}{dx} $$

(2) Multiply the right-hand term by $\frac{dy}{dy}$ (allowable since it is equivalent to 1):

$$ \frac{d\psi}{dx} = \frac{\partial_x \psi}{dx} + \frac{\partial_y \psi}{dx} \frac{dy}{dy} $$

(3) Use the commutative law to rearrange the rightmost term:

$$ \frac{d\psi}{dx} = \frac{\partial_x \psi}{dx} + \frac{\partial_y \psi}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} $$

(4) Rewrite using modern calculus notation:

$$ \frac{d\psi}{dx} = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx} $$

**Another note on the solution.**

A more straightforward way to solve it, in my opinion, is to simply recognize the product rule.

The original equation is:

$$ 2x + y^2 + 2xy\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 $$

Multiplying through by $dx$ yields

$$ 2x\,dx + y^2\,dx + 2xy\,dy = 0 $$

Integrating both sides gives:

$$ \int \left(2x\,dx + y^2\,dx + 2xy\,dy\right) = \int 0 $$

We can break the integral at +s.  In this case, let's just break it at the first plus.

$$ \int 2x\,dx + \int \left(y^2\,dx + 2xy\,dy\right) = \int 0 $$

You can tell that the middle integral is the result of the product rule.  $u = y^2$ and $v = x$.  So that means the middle integral is just $xy^2$.

So the result is:

$$ x^2 + xy^2 = C $$

The whole transition through $\psi$ seems excessive, but it depends on what they are trying to teach.

Comment: This is really neat, thanks! BTW: I got curious about your book, I'll eventually buy it. I also happened to find the notation around dx's and dy's too weird.

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to separate *places* in a function (i.e., which argument is which) and the names of variables occupying those places. Suppose, for instance, that we define
$$
f(x, y) = x^3y
$$
and then ask "What's the derivative of $f(y, x)$ with respect to $x$?" Using the chain rule, one might be tempted to say that it's
$$
\frac{\partial f} {\partial x} \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{\partial f} {\partial y} \frac{dx}{dx},
$$
and untangling that would be a complete mess.

So suppose we agree that if $f$ is a function of two arguments, we'll denote its derivative with respect to the first as $D_1 f$, and similarly for the second. Then the answer becomes clearer, esp. if we add arguments back in place. It's
$$
D_1f (y, x) \frac{dy}{dx} + D_2f (y,x) \frac{dx}{dx},
$$
and assuming that $y$ and $x$ are independent variables here, the first term is zero, so the overall result is just $D_2f (y,x) \frac{dx}{dx}.$

In your case, $x$ and $y$ are used to represent both *places* in the function $\psi$ and something more --- $y$ is supposed to actually be a function of the variable $x$. With that in mind, let's rewrite

$$
\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}
$$

as
$$
D_1 \psi (x, y(x)) + D_2 \psi (x, y(x)) \frac{dy(x)}{dx}.
$$
The is evidently (by the chain rule) the derivative of the function
$$
g(x) = \psi(x, y(x))
$$
with respect to its single argument. It is this function, $g$, that B & D are referring to when at the end they write
$$
\frac{d\psi}{dx}.
$$

It still baffles me that anyone (including me) can make sense of stuff like this, but we all eventually do.

Comment: I don't understand why the first term at $D_1f (y, x) \frac{dy}{dx} + D_2f (y,x) \frac{dx}{dx}$ is zero, could you explain a bit more? By the way: The order of the arguments is reversed in there, is that correct?

Comment: Note that my very first question is "what's the derivative of $f(y, x)$...?" has the arguments reversed as well; that was deliberate, to make a point about the difference between argument names and argument places. Note that $D_1f(y,x)$ should be read as $(D_1 f)(y,x)$, i.e., compute the derivative of $f$ with respect to its first argument, apply that function to the pair $(y,x)$. As to the "first term is zero" question, if $y$ and $x$ are independent variables, then $dy/dx$ is zero (i.e., informally, you can fiddle with $x$ without $y$ changing at all).

Comment: I think I get it: If both $x,y$ are independent variables, then $dy/dx=0$ but if - for example - y depends on x, that statement is false, right?

Comment: Yup --- if $y$ is a (nonconstant) function of $x$, then $dy/dx$ might be nonzero.